# Relaciones de tablas en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy haciendo la edición de un pedido. He añadido un botón a cada fila para poder editar el pedido, y el argumento que le paso es el número de ticket, para abrir el correcto.

Como un pedido puede tener más de una fila, he creado una consulta para sacar todas las filas con el mismo número de ticket.

```
$pedidos = DB::table('orders')
    ->leftJoin('combinations', 'orders.idCombination', '=', 'combinations.id')
    ->select('orders.*', 'combinations.product_id', 'combinations.combination', 'combinations.id AS idCombi')
    ->where('orders.ticket', $ticket)->get();
```

Con esta consulta saco todos los productos para el primer select, que trae todos los productos.

```
$productos = Product::get();
```

Luego en la vista lo itero todo:

```
@foreach ($pedidos as $key => $ped)
   <tr data-fila="{{ $key }}">
     <td>
       <select class="form-control" name="eProducto" style="min-height: 38px;">
          @foreach ($productos as $pro)
             <option value="{{ $pro->id}}" {{ ( $pro->id== $ped->idProducto) ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{ $pro->name }} </option>
           @endforeach
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
      <select class="form-control" name="opcion" style="min-height: 38px;">
          <option value="0">{{ $ped->combination }}</option>
      </select>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

En el primer `td` itero los productos que tengo en la base de datos y lo compruebo con el registro idProducto de la tabla `orders`, de este modo el primer select me trae todos los productos y me marca el que esta seleccionado en el pedido.

Bien luego tengo otro select, que trae la variación que puede tener ese producto. En la tabla `orders` tengo un campo que se llama `idCombination` que esta enlazada con la tabla `combinations` donde guardo las combinaciones posibles. Está tabla tiene:

id
product_id
combination
etc...

Si un mismo producto, pongamos una camiseta esta en dos tallas en la tabla combinations me guardaria:

**Fila 1:**
product_id: 1
combination: combination-s

**Fila 2:**
product_id: 1
combination: combination-l

Bien en el `select name="opcion"` ahora estoy imprimiendo la variación que tiene ese producto en ese pedido, que lo saco con el `leftJoin`
Pero el problema es que quiero sacar las combinaciones que tiene ese producto en la tabla combinations para poder cambiar la opción, por ejemplo si esta `combination-s` poder cambiar a `combination-l`.

Llevo rato haciendo joins, icluso relaciones, pero al controlador no tengo forma de decirle la id del producto que hago en el foreach.

Alguna sugerencia por favor!

Comment: Trata de mejorar tu pregunta, me parece algo extensa y poco clara en el problema presentado por favor

Comment: Hola @BetaM sinceramente no se como plantearla mejor! :S

Comment: Entonces tu problema es que quieres obtener las combinaciones de cada producto que seleccionó anteriormente. Se puede trabajar fácilmente con relaciones, para eso es necesario saber qué tablas intervienen y sus relaciones.

Comment: Hola @L.Flor gracias por tu respuesta, si correcto necesitaba eso, ya lo acabo de conseguir al hacer `joins`  ahora lo publico. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir lo que buscaba he tenido que hacer otra query para relacionar las dos tablas. No se aun utilizar muy bien las relaciones, así que propongo está solución.

```
$numPedido2 = DB::table('orders')
  ->join('combinations', 'orders.idProducto', '=', 'combinations.product_id')
  ->select('orders.ticket',  'combinations.combination', 'combinations.id AS idCombias')
  ->where('orders.ticket', $ticket)
  ->groupby('orders.ticket',  'combinations.combination', 'idCombias')->get();
```

Luego en la vista:

```
<select class="form-control selectSTer js-example-basic-single" name="eTipo[]" style="min-height: 38px;">
    <option value="">Selecciona una opción </option>
       @foreach ($numPedido2 as $item)
         <option value="{{ $item->idCombias}}" {{ ( $item->idCombias== $ped->idCombi) ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{ $item->combination }} </option>
       @endforeach   
</select>
```

Asi consigo marcar la opción marcada en el pedido y las combinaciones posibles de ese producto en el select.